# Change SVG path behaviour with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

This is my experiment with animating SVG path - http://codepen.io/alahab/pen/mydxLK.

```
function simulatePathDrawing(path) {
  //var path = document.querySelector('.squiggle-animated path');

  var length = path.getTotalLength();
  // Clear any previous transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'none';

  // Set up the starting positions
  path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;

  // Trigger a layout so styles are calculated & the browser
  // picks up the starting position before animating
  path.getBoundingClientRect();
  // Define our transition
  path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 5s ease-in-out';

  // Go
  path.style.stroke = '#fff';
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
  path.style.strokeWidth = '1px';
  path.style.fill = '#333';

}

var chars = $('.squiggle-animated path').on('mouseover', function(e) {
  simulatePathDrawing(this);
});
```

As you see when the page loads the color of the path is grey, then it changes to white on mouseover. But i want it to change back to grey when the line is drawn/when the execution is finished. How do i do that?

Also if the path is not finished drawing and you move the mouse away from the shape it draws the path two times. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things happening here:

- On mouseover happens on that 1px width path ... so if you move to the middle of the image, watch the animation, then move the mouse out of the image, you pass over the line again, re-triggering the animation
- You need to remove the mouseover event once the animation has triggered / finished (probably using .off())

Looks really cool!